# Blazor: Awaiting a task of type string within a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, blazor

Lets say we have a Blazor component that displays a list of `Item`, like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Items)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">@item.StartTime.UtcToEst().ToString("MMM dd h:mm tt")</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">GetJobInput(item)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 hidden-lg">
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now, unfortunately, our `Item` class doesn't have a property for its input, which is why we have to pass the item to a helper method `GetJobInput` that retrieve it for us. Now because we are using Blazor, we want to keep everything asynchronous, so we got our items in the first place during `OnParametersSetAsync`:

```
protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    Items = await itemService.GetItems(arg1, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Now, the issue is that because we are already in a `foreach` loop, we can't exactly `await` our `GetJobInput` method:

```
protected async Task<string> GetJobInput(Item item) 
{
   return (await itemSerivce.DescribeItemByName(item.ItemName, item.Arg, CancellationToken.None)).Description?.Input;
}
```

What actually happens is the component renders out the `ToString()` of the `Task` instead of unwrapping it to a string.

Now for as long as I can remember I have been told and have seen that you should rarely ever use `.Result` when dealing with `Task` since that defeats the whole purpose of async. However, from the code I have shown above, it would appear that the only way to unwrap the task within the foreach loop would be to change it to the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">GetJobInput(item).Result</div>
```

But, wouldn't that cause a block on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: The https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358900/calling-async-methods-in-blazor-view which I chose as duplicate answers your question as asked (there is some chance that approach would have trouble with loop - feel free to [edit] post and ping me to re-open)... but I personally think what you trying to do is ... not optimal. It is rarely good idea to issue and wait for results of multiple service calls in  a loop. Usually you start all requests at the same time and wait for all results to come back...