# How to run a foreach inside another foreach using the first foreach's value

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am a beginner at C# and Blazor and this is my problem:

The following `foreach` loop is very simple and works as expected.

```
@if (ClassRoom != null)
{
  @foreach (var cr in ClassRoom.value)
  {
    <p> Classroom name:  @cr.name  </>

    // how to query `cr.url` here ??


  }
}
```

The problem is, inside the foreach loop I need to grab `cr.url` and make another query, which will in turn provide me a list of students in the classroom.

Just like how I got the `ClassRoom`, I also have a model for `Students` and a service that fetches Students as:

```
Students = await StudentsService.GetStudents(url);
```

This means I don't really need help to fetch students. If I give a url to students i.e. `GetStudents("http://example.com/students");` it works.

What I need is how to call it from the foreach loop

#### edit

Inside the foreach loop, if I use

```
Students = await StudentsService.GetStudents(cr.url)
```

I get this error:

```
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
```

Comment: `var r = await StudentsService.GetStudents(cr.name);`? Not really clear what is the problem you are having writing that code... Maybe [edit] the post and make sure to show what you tried and what exact errors (as text) that causes? (Presumably, you already tried not to switch between code and HTML too often, so I guess that is not the issue you are facing)

Comment: I will edit it now, but I get the following error `The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.`

Comment: I believe it should be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358900/calling-async-methods-in-blazor-view but I'm out of votes here (Note that you may want to re-read the question after your edit to make sure the [mre] placed there aligns with the title - I claim the title has absolutely nothing to do with the body of the question... but that's not my call)

Comment: The Title of this question should be along the lines of **'How to call an async method in Blazor'**. The problem you're having has got nothing to do with the `url` property, but with the (async) method that you are trying to call. Unfortunately I have never used Blazor, so I can't help any further...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - You are correct.  However, there's a wider issue illustrated here - loading the Renderer with backend tasks, which I've tried to address with the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not been running the data retrieval code within the render code.  This slows down the Renderer and makes the UI unresponsive.  As has already been pointed out by @Alexei Levenkov, referring to an older  answer, you can't run async code as part of the render process.

Instead, you should build a composite aggregate object in the component code (or, in a clean design, in a ViewModel/Presenter ) and update the display as new data arrives.

Here's a standalone component that demonstrates the principles.

i've made the data methods async with longish delays to demonstrate the UI update as each new class arrives.

```cs
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

@foreach (var classItem in _classes)
{
    <div class="m-2 p-2 border border-dark">
        <table class="table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var student in classItem.Students)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @student.Name
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private readonly List<ClassAggregate> _classes = new List<ClassAggregate>();

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var classes = await GetClasses();
        foreach (var classItem in classes)
        {
            var students = await this.GetStudents(classItem.Uid);
            var classAggregate = new ClassAggregate(Class: classItem, Students: students);
            _classes.Add(classAggregate);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    private async ValueTask<IEnumerable<ClassRecord>> GetClasses()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return new List<ClassRecord>
        {
            new ClassRecord(Uid:Guid.NewGuid(), Name:"Class 1"),
            new ClassRecord(Uid:Guid.NewGuid(), Name:"Class 2"),
            new ClassRecord(Uid:Guid.NewGuid(), Name:"Class 3"),
        };
    }

    private async ValueTask<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudents(Guid classUid)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return new List<Student>
        {
            new Student(Uid:Guid.NewGuid(), ClassUid:classUid, Name:"Student 1"),
            new Student(Uid:Guid.NewGuid(), ClassUid:classUid, Name:"Student 2"),
            new Student(Uid:Guid.NewGuid(), ClassUid:classUid, Name:"Student 3"),
            new Student(Uid:Guid.NewGuid(), ClassUid:classUid, Name:"Student 4"),
            new Student(Uid:Guid.NewGuid(), ClassUid:classUid, Name:"Student 5"),
            new Student(Uid:Guid.NewGuid(), ClassUid:classUid, Name:"Student 6"),
        };
    }

    public record ClassAggregate(ClassRecord Class, IEnumerable<Student> Students);

    public record Student(Guid Uid, Guid ClassUid, string Name);

    public record ClassRecord(Guid Uid, string Name);
}
```

Comment: [Polite] Consider this: 20 classes, 30 students per class, that's 600 records displayed on a very long scrolled page.  Is that the UX you want?  Why not a select for a class and showing just one class?

Comment: just one question because the code is a lot more than I expected. If I haave a `ClassRoomModel` and `StudentModel` I don't need to create the second and third `ValueTask` methods right? Just only use `ClassAggregate` and combine the two models?

Comment: Correct.  Load everything into the one aggregate object.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because you show how it can be done to request multiple dependant requests. But for some reason my issue is not resolved. Can you please take a look at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75464937/how-to-fetch-a-second-api-based-on-the-response-of-a-first-api I have simplified it, let me know if you can the solution

Comment: I Will have a look for you.